# Ruby symbol to class

Tags: ruby, class, transform, symbols

Is there a way in Ruby to take a symbol or string and turn it into a class of the same name?

For instance, if I have a class such as

```
class Bob
  def talk
     puts "Hi, I'm bob"
  end
end
```

And a method I have somewhere else in the code is passed a symbol :bob, can I in some way turn that into the class Bob?  Maybe something like

```
b = :Bob.new
b.talk
```

Or is there a way to do something similar to this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Your lack of context makes it impossible to elect a "best" way. Here's a few ayways.

```
Kernel.const_get(:Bob)

eval(:Bob.to_s)

Kernel.const_get(:bob.to_s.capitalize)
```

Comment: Well, thankfully I didn't ask for the "best" way, but just a way... ;)

Comment: just for the case, if `Bob` is defined in module `People` and you know it, you can `People.const_get(:Bob)`

Answer (score 45):

### Rails

*For use with Rails only.*

With a string:

```
"Module".constantize #=> Module
"Class".constantize #=> Class
```

With a symbol:

```
:module.to_s.classify.constantize #=> Module
:open_struct.to_s.classify.constantize #=> OpenStruct
```

If you are dealing with a *multi-word* symbol, then you'll want to add `#classify` to the chain to properly handle the capitalization of all the parts of the constant.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize

Comment: Sorry, I should probably add that this is a Rails only thing.

Comment: If you're using Rails this is probably the best solution.

Comment: The question specifically asks about symbols and constantize does not exist on the Symbol class in Rails. Answer should be `:Module.to_s.constantize`.

Answer (score 10):

None of the solutions I've seen work if you want to turn :foo_bar into FooBar.  If that's what you're looking for:

> :foo_bar.to_s.split("_").collect(&:capitalize).join.constantize
>   => FooBar

hope that helps someone.

Comment: That's what 'camelize' is for: :foo_bar.to_s.camelize

Comment: @DaveSims `camelize` is an ActiveRecord extension: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize, although so is `constantize`.

Comment: Yes, like Dan Frade, I should have mentioned that. :)

Answer (score 5):

`NameSpace.const_get(classname)` will return the class object (assuming that classname contains the name of a class - if it contains the name of a constant that is not a class, it will return the value of that constant). The toplevel namespace is Object, so you can do `Object.const_get(:Bob).new`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Bob
end

def create(name)
  return eval("#{name}.new")
end

b = create(:Bob)
puts b.class
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that I came up with while looking for something similar that included module/namespace support:

```
['foo', 'bar'].inject {|r,e| "#{r.classify}::#{e.classify}"}.constantize
```

Produces

```
=> Foo::Bar
```

However this requires Rails and of course it only works where the array has more than one element.

This seems rather simple so I'm sure I'm missing something out, would anyone care to advise why this wouldn't be a good approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking a question inside of an answer? For shame! ;)

Comment: @JustinStolle, I don't think its a new question, more guidance regarding to the original question? :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, both example below worked, but you also have not to forget namespace:

```
  Object.const_get("ModuleName::#{class_model_name}")
```

or

```
  Kernel.const_get("ModuleName::#{class_model_name}").
```